# Как решить задачу c классом эрик мэтиз python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Изучаю программирование по книге самоучителю, решаю задачу с классом.

Ресторан: создайте класс с именем `Restaurant`. Метод `__init__()` класса `Restaurant` должен содержать два атрибута: `restaurant_name` и `cuisine_type`. Создайте метод `describe_restaurant()`, который выводит два атрибута, и метод `open_restaurant()`, который выводит сообщение о том, что ресторан открыт. Создайте на основе своего класса экземпляр с именем `restaurant`. Выведите два атрибута по отдельности, затем вызовите оба метода.

***Мой примерный код:***

```py
class Restaurant():
    
 def _init_(self, name, tip):
   self.name = name
   self.tip = tip
   
 def describe_restaurant():
     print("Hello, visitor!" + self.name.title() + "welcome to you!")
 def open_restaurant():
     print("It is" + self.tip)

my_restaurant = ['natalia' , 'ukrainian']
print("Hello, visitor!")
print(describe_restaurant())
```

Comment: 'Создайте метод describe_ restaurant(), который выводит 2 атрибута' у вас 1.  'метод open_restaurant(), который выводит сообщение о том, что ресторан открыт' у вас выводит чтото другое.у вас отсутствует 'Создайте на основе своего класса экземпляр' .'Выведите два атрибута по отдельности, затем вызовите оба метода.' у вас не реализовано.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/OptimalFairAlgorithms#main.py

Comment: @nomnoms12 сделал 7 попыток и 'Failed to connect' не открывается

Comment: @Интик Странно. У меня открывается (пробовал также через инкогнито и VPN).

Comment: @nomnoms12 проверил еще. не работает. может проблема что я с телефона ?

Comment: Что такое эрик мэтиз?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы создать экземпляр класса нужно сделать следующее:

```
# теперь в переменной r содержится экземпляр класса
r = Restaurant(name='test', type='test')
# можно менять свойства экземпляра класса
r.name = 'first_restaurant'
# или вызывать методы класса
r.open_restaurant()
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем, судя по коду, не добавлен `self` в метод `describe_restaurant()`, а также в `open_restaurant()`. Именно поэтому в обоих выводах ничего не вывелось. Также, методы вообще не вызваны, что крайне печально, ведь в книге должен описываться пример построения класса. Плюс ко всему, неправильно записаны данные о ресторане, имя и тд.

```
class Restaurant:
    def __init__(self, r_name, cuisine_type):
        self.r_name = r_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print("\nRestaurant name: " + self.r_name.title())
        print("Restaurant type: " + self.cuisine_type.title())
    def open_restaurant(self):
        print("Restaurant" + self.r_name.title() + "is open!")

my_restaurant = Restaurant(" Harbin ", "asian food")
my_restaurant.describe_restaurant()
my_restaurant.open_restaurant()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
class Restaurant():
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        '''' метод выводит название ресторана и кухню'''
        name_type = f"Ресторан:{self.restaurant_name}, Кухня:{self.cuisine_type}"
        return name_type.title()

    def describe_restaurant_name(self):
        '''' метод выводит название ресторана'''
        name_rest = f"Название ресторана: {self.restaurant_name}"
        return name_rest.title()

    def describe_restaurant_cuisine(self):
        '''' метод выводит  кухню ресторана'''
        cuisine_rest = f"Кухня в ресторане: {self.cuisine_type}"
        return cuisine_rest.title()

    def open_restaurant(self):
        '''' метод выводит  информацию, что ресторан открыт'''
        return "Ресторан открыт"

restaurant = Restaurant('Уральские пельмени', 'пельмени и варенники' )

print(restaurant.describe_restaurant_name()) # печатаю название ресторана
print(restaurant.describe_restaurant_cuisine()) # печатаю тип кухни в ресторане
print('Название ресторана и кухня: ',restaurant.describe_restaurant()) # # печатаю название и тип кухни в ресторане
print(restaurant.open_restaurant()) # сообщение, что ресторан открыт

print(restaurant.describe_restaurant(), restaurant.open_restaurant()) # Имя и кухня ресторана + сообщение, что ресторан открыт
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]